# How to calculate standard error of mean concentration of samples with standard errors in each sample

Tags: regression, standard-error, error-propagation

I've been surfing Cross Validated trying to find an answer to this question of mine, and I've found these posts: [Standard deviation of mean of a set of numbers, which are imprecise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210491/standard-deviation-of-mean-of-a-set-of-numbers-which-are-imprecise), [Standard deviation of several measurements with uncertainties](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94109/standard-deviation-of-several-measurements-with-uncertainties), and [How would I compute the standard deviation of data with errors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251275/how-would-i-compute-the-standard-deviation-of-data-with-errors). I'm not sure they really answer the exact question I have or that they would apply correctly to my data. If they do answer my question, I'm really too inexperienced in statistics to have realized.

Anyway, this involves a bit of analytical chemistry. I have two sets of blood plasma samples from two different patient populations with concentrations of a certain glycoprotein of interest in each, calculated from a linear regression set up with standards. Calculating the confidence interval for each patient sample concentration was not difficult. According to [Chemistry LibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/BethuneCookman_University/B-CU%3A_CH-345_Quantitative_Analysis/Book%3A_Analytical_Chemistry_2.1_(Harvey)/05%3A_Standardizing_Analytical_Methods/5.04%3A_Linear_Regression_and_Calibration_Curves), the standard deviation in each sample concentration is given by

$$
s_{x}=\frac{s_{r}}{b}\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(\overline{Y}-\overline{y})^2}{b^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{i}-\overline{x})^2}}\tag 1
$$

where $m$ is the number of replicate measurements conducted on a single sample; $n$ is the number of calibration standards; $\overline{Y}$ is the sample signal average after the replicate measurements; $\overline{y}$ is the signal average of all calibration standard; $x_i$ is a single standard concentration; $\overline{x}$ is the average of all standard concentrations; $s_{r}$ is the standard deviation about the regression; and $b$ is the y-intercept of the regression. The confidence interval for each individual sample concentration is apparently just

$$\textrm{CI}=x\pm t_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2},\space n-2)}s_{x}\tag 2$$

which is justified by the fact that there is only one linear regression being used according to Chemistry LibreTexts, so $\sqrt{n}=1$ (different $n$ from equation 1). So far so good. I then went on to calculate the concentrations of my samples and average them together (I assumed that the values for each patient population were probably close to being normally distributed, so the sample size of each is, I think, sufficiently large for the Central Limit Theorem to apply. I'm okay with using a t-distribution for everything). At this point, I realized that I have no clue how to calculate a final standard error for the average concentration for each set of samples at some arbitrary confidence level while considering the standard error of a desired confidence in each sample concentration. If someone could guide me in figuring this out, I would greatly appreciate it. I've never actually taken a statistics course, however I've been learning along the way. That being said, my grasp on certain concepts can be mediocre at best, so I might need some clarifications to answers. If you would like to include a proof, please do. I'm always happy to see some rigor in answers. And if any information in this question is unclear or missing, I would be more than happy to elaborate or provide more information.

Comment: I think what you need is a properly weighted mean. When each measurement has a measured error, the best estimate of the mean will give greater weight to those with lower intrinsic error -- o weight each $x_i$ by the inverse variance $1/s_i^2$. The weighted mean $\mu = (\sum_i x_i/s_i^2)/(\sum_i 1/s_i^2)$ has a sample standard variance $\sigma^2 = (\sum_i )/(\sum_i 1/s_i^2)$, which reduces to $s^2/n$ as expected when all errors $s$ are equal. I'm not finding a good reference (esp. one that points out the assumptions like independence of measurements, checking consistency of results, etc.)

Comment: @jwimberley I see. So I'm guessing my best bet would probably be to include the standard error of the estimator of the mean as a separate point of information from just the plain standard error of the mean as a way for someone to assess the results of the analysis. Thank you for the suggestion.